# How to suppress the unsolicited footer when converting HTML -> PDF with Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, file-conversion

I often convert & combine (via contextmenu) HTML pages to PDF using Acrobat (not Acrobat Reader). I use Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 Extended, version 9.1.2. The converted PDFs always have the full path of the original file on the bottom of the PDF-page, also they have an additional header line with the document.

I need to suppress that. I do not want the unsolicited header and footer in the resulting PDF files as they are a pain to reomve manually, with a certain page count per document it becomes impossible.

Is it possible to suppres that and if, how?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webmasterworld.com/webmaster/3917336.htm?highlight=msg3934794

This might be a work-around for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Adobe Acrobat installed right now, so I can't remember the direct answer to your question, but couldn't you just load the HTML files in a web browser (or even a Word Processor), and print to Distiller to create a PDF? Firefox at least lets you pick the headers and footers, and leave them blank if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote I convert & combine many HTML pages. If I'd use your soultion, I would have to manually convert each single HTML page. I don't think it's practicable to change the workflow I am currently using, I need to get rid of the header & footer, not use an entirely different approach.

Comment: If I had a lot of them to do, I wouldn't use Acrobat at all. Acrobat is horribly, slow bloated software; not something to use for batch processing. There are other options out there that could do html > pdf conversions from the command-line, like PrinceXML or AbiWord. You could then write a batch file or script that combined the outputs using pdftk or similar, and you wouldn't have to process things one by one at all.

Comment: Admittedly I have one issue with the header and footer, but apart from that I think Acrobat is a terrific piece of software and much better for my purposes than AbiWord, thanks. I sense this repeating pattern on so many forums: Q: I have a problem with X. A: Then why don't you do Y or use Z instead. Don't get me wrong, it's nice that you are trying to help but stackexchange is to solve problems, not circumvent problems.

Comment: The only thing that makes AbiWord better here is the scripting ability, and the fact that it's free (both open source and free in cost). A lot of power users have either philosophical preferences for free software, economic reasons, practical reasons, or all three. If you insist on doing this with expensive commercial software, for which you paid for customer support, then whey not just ask Adobe?

Comment: That's simple; I have philosophical preferences for the Pirate Bay (free as in beer), and they don't have customer support.